# how to change from address in sending mail in outlook using python win32

Tags: python, automation, win32com

I have the following code and i need to change the from address.

```
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

mail.To = 'madanraj.c@xyz.com;madanraj.c@xxxyyy.com'

mail.Subject = 'Daily Backlog'

mail.Body = 'This Mail is Sent by Python'

mail.HTMLBody = '<h2>HTML Message body</h2>' #this field is optional

# To attach a file to the email (optional):
#attachment  = "C:\\Users\madanraj.c\Downloads\Report.csv"
#mail.Attachments.Add(attachment)


mail.Send()
print("success")
```

I have two mail address in my outlook application and i need to send from other one , not by default one.